# Reject issue: "We are not able to continue because we need a demo QR code or AR marker (image) to fully assess your app features."

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, qr-code

I have a project in a flutter. It has QR code scanner and the QR code is generated from the web and is called using API. QR code scanner scans the QR-code to get the information of the user. I submitted my app and got rejected saying :

> ```
> We have started the review of your app, but we are not able to continue 
> because we need a demo QR code or AR marker (image) to fully assess your 
> app features.
> ```

Next Steps

> ```
> To help us proceed with the review of your app, please provide the demo 
> details in the App Review Information section for your app in App Store 
> Connect or reply to this message with the requested demo information. 
> Please ensure that the information you provide includes any data necessary 
> to demonstrate the functionality of your app features.
> ```

To provide QR codes or images information:

> ```
> - Log in to App Store Connect
> - Click on "My Apps"
> - Select your app
> - Click on the app version on the left side of the screen
> - Scroll down to "App Review Information"
> - Provide information in "Notes" as appropriate
> - Click "Save"
> - Once you've completed all changes, click the "Save" button at the top of 
> the Version Information page.
> ```

Then I created a demo video to use QR code scanner and wrote some

> notes as:
>
> ```
>   *The QR code image for each user is provided from our API and set on 
>   lock 
>   screen by the user.
>   *The purpose of the camera permission is to scan the QR code. 
>   *The Scanned QR code returns the details uploaded by the user whose 
>   phone is lost. A demo video is attached on attachment.
> ```

I again submitted to the app store and still, it rejected saying the same error as above. I couldn't find the possible solutions. Anyone could help me?

Comment: did you provide them account with everything set up?

Answer (score 1):

You need to give them the QR code (may be the qr code image) so they can scan and check your app feature/functionality. (Provide access to your web to generate QR-code, if possible)

Also include a detailed notes (including steps, data, etc.) about this feature/functionality.

**Possible Rejection reason**

> It might possible that they were scanning the QR code but they may not proceed with the invalid QR-code scanning. Thats the reason they ask for the QR-code demo (QR-code image) so that can use in review process.

Answer (score 1):

> I have faced the same rejection earlier. To approve my app, I have given
>   the sample URL, Which basically contains an image of the QR Code. By using this URL reviewer team can review the whole
>   functionality of the app.

Also, Give some step or video which is helpful to the reviewer team.

[Sample QR image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YBUmYi2dpZ1C280cc-Je1mts9Qb3eyjG/view?usp=sharing)

That's it!